# Shall I Questions

Tags: politeness, will-be-going

> 1. Shall I find out for you?
> 2. Shall I open the door for you?
> 3. Shall I pull these curtains back now?

Please, I want to choose one of the following for each question.

- a) Do you want that I
- b) Shall I
- c) Will I
- d) Would you like that I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a) and (d) are ungrammatical. (c) doesn’t convey the meaning that I think you have in mind. (b) is grammatical, and is one way of making an offer, but it may sound a little too formal for some.

Perhaps the most universally acceptable construction would be ‘Would you like me to open the door for you?’

Comment: Thanks, But what about the meaning is it matter?? at the 1st and 2nd sentences are suggestion but at the 3rd sentence is a question"request".

Comment: Should this start "(a) and (d) are..." rather than "(a) and (b) are..."? I wouldn't presume to just go ahead and edit...

Comment: @framawi. I'm not sure which sentences you're talking about. If you mean the first three senences in your post, then all three could be seen as making an offer, but we can't be sure without knowing the exact circumstances.